# Text Mining in R - how to exclude full phrases/sentences from text analysis

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm working on around 160 separate responses to a survey. I've ran R code to produce, after cleaning, a simple wordcloud and some sensitivity analysis.
However, the analysis includes all the text from the template which the respondents were asked to complete, such as the introductory text, instructions, name, company, address, along with all the section headings and questions presented.
As all of this template text will be repeated for each of the 160 responses, it is skewing the frequency of words in the responses.
Is there a method in R to exclude not just single words (as per stopwords or creating mystopwords) but full sentances or phrases from the analysis so all text in the template can be ignored and not included as part of the set of responses?
I am unable to share responses due to confidentality but I can share the blank template which contains all the text I wish to exclude from analysis, available at https://www.economy-ni.gov.uk/energy-strategy-call-for-evidence.

Dummy data in R:

[50] "2. Energy in Northern Ireland"
  [51] "Q1. What lessons can we learn from elsewhere in addressing energy within an"
  [52] "overarching climate action framework?"
  [53] "Q2. What are the key considerations for decarbonising Northern Ireland’s energy"
  [54] "sector given existing linkages to other jurisdictions?"
  [55] "Q3. To what extent should Northern Ireland implement the key energy-related"
  [56] "recommendations from the CCC ‘Reducing Emissions in Northern Ireland’"
  [57] "report?"
  [58] "Q4. Do you agree with the 30-year timeframe? If not, please state your preferred"
  [59] "approach and reasons."
  [60] “Respondent response text xxxxxxxx  blahblahvlahblah”
  [61] "3. The Energy Transition in Northern Ireland"
  [62] "Q5. What are the unique characteristics of Northern Ireland that need to be"
  [63] "considered in a net zero carbon energy transition?"
  [64] "Q6. Is your organisation undertaking or planning to undertake projects to support"
  [65] "the energy transition? If so, please provide further details."
  [66] “Respondent response text xxxxxxxx  blahblahvlahblah”

Within this subset of the data, I wish to exclude standard text in rows 50 to 59 and again rows 61 to 65 as these contains the same text through all responses i.e. each row across all responses will begin with the same text each time.

The rows begining *Respondent response text* are only dummy data for illustration purposes and will be different each time a section/questions are being repsonded to. In this example, I would be seeking to keep the text in rows 60 and 66 for the analysis.

The standard text, to exclude, will not always be the in same row number across each response/file. This is caused by the responses running over multiple rows.

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: You need to describe more clearly what you take to be "standard text", which you you seem to want to exclude, and "responses", which you seem to want to keep. That description needs to include 'rules'; for example, do responses always start with the term "Respondent response text", does standard text always start with "Q + number + period", and so on. Given a set of such rules mining your text data is definitely feasible. Also, the last sentence of your post is, well, syntactically hard to parse, thus contributing to comprehension difficulties of the readers.

Comment: Hi Chris. New to all this and understand I need to get better so appreciate the tips. I've edited the text above but in brief the rules: Responses to the quetsions can start with anything, noting standard. The standrad elements are the headings (2. Energy etc) and questions (beginning with Q or the next line down and finishes with a ?). These standard elements are those I wish to exclude from text analysis.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear: in your post you say you want to "keep the text in rows 60 and 66 for the analysis" but in the comment you say "standrad elements are the headings (2. Energy etc)", which you want to exclude. However row 61 ""3. The Energy Transition in Northern Ireland" seems to be just such a heading.

Comment: Sorry Chris, all rows bar row 60 and 66, in this example, are to be excluded from analysis. 
So rows 50-59 cover the heading and questions for section 2, while rows 61-65 cover the heading and questions for section 3. These rows will begin with the same (standard) text across each response file. They just won’t be the same row number each time.
There are more sections and questions in the document, which will follow the pattern of standard text (heading and questions) then respondent’s response. I’m only showing two sections here for illustration.
Does that help?

Comment: So the text you want to extract always starts with "“Respondent response text xxxxxxxx blahblahvlahblah” and ends with either a Section number + period or a Q plus number plus period?

Comment: The extract I wish to keep could start with anything, I only put that text in as dummy data as can't share the real text. But yu are correct in that the text I wish to keep would end with a section number + period or a Q plus number plus period.

Comment: Ok, so the end point is clear. But you also need to define some kind of rule for the beginning.

Comment: Is the rule for the beginning the next row after end of the last question of the section e.g. the text in row 59 will always be followed by the respondents response, this might run over a number of rows (dummy data is only for a single row) and the end/break in the response is the next common/standard text which is the heading for section 3, as in the text in row 61. Is there a way of creating flags at these start and end points and extract what's inbetween?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the pieces you want always start with 'Respondent ...' but if they do you could do something simple like

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
filter(str_starts(your_data_column, 'Respondent'))
```

Comment: Thanks CER. I could maybe use this in reverse. The questions in the document are the same text through each response file while the Respondent text will differ across each file i.e. the piece I want to keep do not always start with 'Respondent'. this was only added for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an initial approach to your text mining problem (initial given the difficulties defining the rules).

First off, some data (note I've added some more respondent strings):

```
x <- c("2. Energy in Northern Ireland",
       "Q1. What lessons can we learn from elsewhere in addressing energy within an",
       "overarching climate action framework?",
       "Q2. What are the key considerations for decarbonising Northern Ireland’s energy",
       "sector given existing linkages to other jurisdictions?",
       "Q3. To what extent should Northern Ireland implement the key energy-related",
       "recommendations from the CCC ‘Reducing Emissions in Northern Ireland’",
       "report?",
       "Q4. Do you agree with the 30-year timeframe? If not, please state your preferred",
       "approach and reasons.",
       "Respondent response text xxxxxxxx blahblahvlahblah",
       "blahblablah and so on",
       "3. The Energy Transition in Northern Ireland",
       "Q5. What are the unique characteristics of Northern Ireland that need to be",
       "considered in a net zero carbon energy transition?",
       "Q6. Is your organisation undertaking or planning to undertake projects to support",
       "the energy transition? If so, please provide further details.",
       "Respondent response text xxxxxxxx blahblahvlahblah",
       "blah blah blah and so on",
       "some more blah blah")
```

The solution now first pastes the strings together with `paste` and then, using `gsub`, removes those parts occurring between (header) numbers and `?`as well as sentences starting with `If`:

```
trimws(gsub("\\d.*\\?|If.*\\.", "", paste(x, collapse = " ")))
```

Result:

```
[1] "Respondent response text xxxxxxxx blahblahvlahblah blah blah blah and so on some more blah blah"
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Chris, thanks for the help and your patience on this. My initial code collapsed the data already and wondering running this again has cuased a problem as very little text results after running this new line. My initial code along with your suggsted line hello

Comment: # set pathway to text files
folder<-"C:\\xxxxx\\Text files"
# lists all files in pathway 
list.files(path=folder)
# filters text files only
list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")

# set vector
filelist<-list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")

Comment: # set vector
filelist<-list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")

# assign pathways to files
paste(folder, "\\", filelist)
# removes separations in pathways by setting as empty
filelist<-paste(folder, "\\", filelist, sep="")

Comment: # apply a function to read in multiple txt files - warnings are OK
a<-lapply(filelist, FUN=readLines)
# apply a function to collaspe into a single element
corpus<-lapply(a, FUN=paste, collaspe=" ")

head(corpus, 30)

trimws(gsub("\\d.*\\?|If.*\\.", "", paste(corpus, collapse = " ")))

head(corpus, 30)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand this, is there anthing you want me to do with this code?

Comment: Sorry Chris, no just to say adding your suggested code at the end here wipes out basically all the text. Never mind it gives me something to think about as a tactic to solve this. Thanks again